# On open sets and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $U$ is an open set. Let $E \subset U$ be a closed set. Is it true that $U \sim E$ is an open set?

My reasoning is that $U \sim E = U \cap (\sim E)$ and since $U$ and $\sim E$ are both open sets, a finite intersection of open sets is open. Hence $U \sim E$ is open.

Likewise, can I use the same reasoning to argue that if $U$ is a closed set and $E \subset U$ is an open set, $U \sim E$ is a closed set?

The topology and the sets that I am considering here are all general.

Comment: Well, in your second example... $U-E$ is closed and so $U \cap (U-E)$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets (over any indexing set even uncountable will do).

Comment: Your argument seems fine (though a point on notation $\sim$ often means some sort of equivalence relation. Either subtraction (like what is used in Chris's comment) or $U \backslash E$ are more standard)

Comment: Late  Learner do you feel comfortable enough with our proof that you could write up your own answer? If not what makes you uneasy in the proof?

Comment: @Gage Learning a new subject right now, so I kind of have no intuition to rely on and I am rather unsure of even the basic facts like this one.

Comment: Ok, I am hoping that we will be able to get your question "answered" but I am having trouble understanding what your concern is. As of right now I'd say that the reasoning in your proof is all valid (and in such cases it may be appropriate to self answer your question) but if there is some part of the proof you feel unsure about I'd love to hear which part and what you feel unsure about with it so I can help clarify for you.

Comment: @Gage I am actually still in the process of learning to write proofs. Some of my questions are more about asking if there are refinements to my proofs. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002633/if-set-e-is-not-connected-then-e-is-separable.

Comment: @Gage I will be very happy if you can give suggestions on how to improve my proof there. I think good proofs are not just right, but elegant and succinct. I am trying to master that art.