# If set E is not connected, then E is separable

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that if the set $E$ is not connected, then $E$ is also separable. The **only definitions that I am going to use** are that a set in a general topological space is connected if and only if the only clopen sets are the set itself and the empty set in the *relative topology*. A set $E$ is separable if and only if $E = A \cup B$ such that $A \cup \bar{B} = \bar{A} \cup B = \emptyset$.

Given a topological space with a set $S$. Consider a set $E \subset S$ and suppose that $E$ is not connected. Let $A'$ be an open set in $S$. Suppose that $A = A' \cap E$. Then we have $A \subset E$ such that $A$ is clopen in the *relative topology*. We note that $B = E-A \ne \emptyset$ and $B = E-A$ is also clopen in the *relative topology*. Hence there exist an open set $B'$ in $S$ such that $B = B' \cap E$.

We first show that $A \cap B' = \emptyset$. Suppose to the contrary there is a point $y \in A, B'$. Since $y \in A$ and $A = A' \cap E$, $y \in E$. Since $y \in B'$ and $y \in E$, hence $y \in B$, which is a contradiction since $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

We note that $E = A \cup (E-A)$ and we claim that $A$ and $(E-A)$ are separated sets.

$A$ and $(E-A)$ are disjoint by definition, so if we can show that no limit point of $A$ is in $(E-A)$ and vice versa, we are done with the proof.

We go by contradiction. Suppose a limit point $x \in A$ is also in $(E-A)$. By the definition of a limit point, all open neighbourhoods of $x$ must intersect $A$. Since  $x \in B \subset B'$, $x$ is in the open neighbourhood B', which is a contradiction since $A \cap B' = \emptyset$ as shown in paragraph 3.

Hence, no limit point of $A$ is in $B$ and vice versa and hence $A \cup \bar{B} = \bar{A} \cup B = \emptyset$.

Hence if $E$ is not connected, then $E$ is separable.

Is it true in general that $E$ is connected if and only if it is separable?

Comment: This is not the standard definition of "separable" (= has a countable sense subset), and you mixed up $\cap$ and $\cup$ a few times.

Comment: You can make it shorter: A set $B$ is closed in $E \subset S$ iff $B = E \cap B'$, where $B'$ is closed in $S$. You have shown that $A \cap B' = \emptyset$. Then $A \cap \text{Cl}_{S}(B) = \emptyset$ because $\text{Cl}_{S}(B) \subset B'$. You get the desired result by swapping $B$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think in general your proof is correct but it definitely felt like it winded around instead of getting to the point.

Yes it is true in general that $E$ is not connected if and only if it is separable.

Proof:

Suppose that $E$ is not connected then there is a clopen set $A \subset E$ such that $A$ is neither $E$ nor $\emptyset$. Now because $A$ is neither all of $E$ nor empty neither is $B = E - A$ and because $A$ is both open and closed so is $B$. Now since $A$ and $B$ are both open and closed we have that they satisfy the requirements that $A \cup B = E$ and they are disjoint (they are their own closures) and we have that $E$ is separable.

Suppose that $E$ is separable then we have non empty open sets $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = E$ and $A \cap \bar{B} = \bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$. From this we can check that $A = \bar{A}$ (and similarly $B = \bar{B}$) for if we have a pint $x \in \bar{A} - A$ then we still know that $x \in A \cup B$ with would tell us that $X \in B$ but this is impossible since $\bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$ so we have that $\bar{A}$ must be $A$. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are clopen sets of $E$ that are neither $E$ nor are they empty and $E$ is not connected.

Comment: In the last paragraph, why does $x \in \bar{A} - A$ also mean that $x \in A \cup B$? We only know that $x \in \bar{A}$ and $\bar{A}$ might not even be a subset of $E$ right?

Comment: @LateLearner I was just writing about $E$ being a space so everything mentioned must be contained in it. In your example of $E$ being a subspace then you can view $E$ as a space with the subspace topology.

Comment: In which case while $A$ might not be equal to $\bar{A}$ in your bigger space $S$ it is in $E$.

Comment: But if $E \subset S$ where $S$ is the bigger space it is still true that $E$ is connected if and only if it is separable right?

Comment: Yes, you can follow this proof for $E \subset S$ by giving $E$ the subspace topology. Maybe this will clarify a little http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition